# Is there any difference between C c; and C c = C();?

Tags: c++, initialization, copy-constructor, default-constructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class C{
private:
    int value;
public:
    C(){
        value = 0;
        cout<<"default constructor"<<endl;
    }
    C(const C& c){
        value = c.value;
        cout<<"copy constructor"<<endl;
    }
};
int main(){
    C c1;
    C c2 = C();
}
```

**Output**:

default constructor

default constructor

**Question**:

For `C c1;` default constructor will be called obviously, for `C c2 = C();` I thought default constructor will be called to initialize a temporary object, then copy constructor will be call to initialize c2, It seems that I am wrong. why?

Comment: Keywords: return value optimization, copy elision.

Comment: Because compiler is smarter than you think.

Comment: Keywords: *value initialization*, *copy initialization*.

Comment: Thanks to @Nicky. Best answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of copy elision - basically the compiler is allowed to optimize away the copy. Described here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision